# Unity coroutine not work as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Hello friends< i am having hard time with unity coroutines. Let"s say I start a coroutine. When I stop should the code below yield be executed0? I THINK NO.
AM I WRONG? here is my code

```
[PunRPC]
public void timerstart(){
    StopCoroutine(time ());
    currentplayerbar.fillAmount=1.0f;
    currentplayerbar=timebar[turn-1];
    StartCoroutine(time());
    Debug.Log("time started");
}

IEnumerator time(){
    Debug.Log("start coroutine");
    timer=60;
    timerisruning=true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(60);

    Debug.Log("60 sec passed");
    timerisruning=false;
    if(id==turn){
        if (passnumber==3){
            //StartCoroutine (noplayeractivity ());

        }

        else {


            passnumber++;
            turn+=1;
            Hashtable turnbupdate=new Hashtable (){{"turn",turn},{"pass",passnumber}};
            PhotonNetwork.room.SetCustomProperties(turnbupdate);
            photonView.RPC("timerstart",PhotonTargets.All);
            PhotonNetwork.SendOutgoingCommands();
        }
    }




}
```

In debugger I see four debug logs  Debug.Log("60 sec passed"); withpout any 
Debug.Log("start coroutine"); beetwen. I think that they are runing in paralel but why? I stopped coroutine before started  new one

Comment: This is the wrong place for this question. Since your question is about the Unity Game Engine, you should use the "Unity3d" tag.

Comment: I did that. see better

Comment: In case you misunderstood me: You had used the "Unity" tag, which is about a different technology rather than the Unity Engine. I tell you this in case you may ask more questions in the future concerning the Unity Engine, in which case the "Unity3d" tag is appropriate.

Comment: Ok sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `StopCoroutine(time ());` you're not stopping the previously started coroutine. You're creating a new coroutine, without starting it and ending it in the same line.

You can fix it in two ways:

1. Call them not by reference but reflection - simply put, change the calls to:

   ```
   StopCoroutine("time");
   ...
   StartCoroutine("time");
   ```
2. Store the running coroutine in a variable

   ```
   var coroutine:IEnumerator;

   [PunRPC]
   public void timerstart(){
       if(coroutine != null)
         StopCoroutine(coroutine);
       ...
       coroutine=time();
       StartCoroutine(coroutine);
   }
   ```